# SolrMeter only works with default Solr core (collection1)

Tags: solr, solrmeter

I have installed 4.7.1 Solr. It already comes with the following core:
/example/solr/collection1

I have added the following core:
/example/solr/itembuckets

I want to test the performance of Solr using SolrMeter. But I am not able to get the SolrMeter to look into itembuckets core. Here is what I have tried so far:

1. I set the value for "URL Solr" to 
   `http://localhost:8983/solr`
2. Since I just want to use itembuckets core, I moved collection1 core to a back up folder.

Problem:
SolrMeter could not detect a Solr instance at this location. Therefore, all SolrMeter buttons (like the play button and the "Optimize Now" button were in red).
To correct this issue, from the menu bar, I selected Edit>Settings. In "Query Settings" tab, for field "URL Solr", I changed the URL as followed:
`http://localhost:8983/solr/itembuckets`

I also changed this value under tab "Update Settings", for field "URL Solr".

When I click on OK to save this change, all play buttons turn green. So SolrMeter should be able to find a Solr instance at the address provided. But when I click on play button in "Query Console" section to start the load testing, I am not able to execute any successful queries. Instead, I keep getting the following error in the error log:
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: Server at `http://localhost:8983/solr/itembuckets` returned non ok status:400, message:Bad Request

I have verified the following link returns status "OK":
`http://localhost:8983/solr/itembuckets/admin/ping`

What do I need to do to set up SolrMeter with my new core (itembuckets)?

Answer (score 1):

1.select **Edit>Settings>Query settings**
  In Query settings   select **Choose  the query mode>external**
  then select **Queries file path** to upload text file containing query.

Note : Your txt file contain query like this q=issue+server&wt=json&indent=true

Answer (score 0):

Try hitting Apply and then OK. I am using Solr 4.8 and it works for me.